# Well defined expected value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider the set of all random variables with E(X)=0 and $E(X^2)<{\infty}$.
Is $E(X)$ well defined?

My approach: because the expected value $E$ is defined as

$$E(X):=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)} x\,P(X=x)$$
and $$E(X^2):=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)} x^2\,P(X=x)<{\infty}$$

The expected value $E(X^2)$ is unique to X.

I tried to proof this but could not succeed with that. So how do I proof this?
thanks in advance

Comment: If you're assuming that $E(X)=0$ then of course $E(X)$ is well defined. It equals $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\sum_{x\in X(\Omega ) }x^2\Pr [X=x]$ converges then it imply that there are at most finitely many $x\in X(\Omega) $ such that $x^2\Pr [X=x]\geqslant 1$. Let $A:=\{x\in X(\Omega) :x^2\Pr [X=x]\geqslant 1\}$ then $|\sum_{x\in A}x\Pr [X=x]|<\infty $ as it is a finite sum, and $|x|\Pr [X=x]\leqslant x^2\Pr [X=x]$ in $A^\complement $, so the result follows.